# How to get notification from about newly added topics or queue?

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, notifications, azure-queues, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm new Azure developer. My scenario is something like manager will publish new topic/queue by website/wp8 and worker should get notification (by push notification) in wp8 about newly added topic/queue. At this moment I have all the pieces ready such as topic/queue creation, sending receiving. But it works on pulling basis. Meaning manager can crate topic and publish message. Then worker has to subscribe to the topic for receiving message and pull every time to check is there anything new?.

So I want to make this system based on notification. I meant whenever anything newly added in topic user should get a notification (by push notification). So can you suggest me how can I achieve this goal? Is there any event generates from service bus if topic added or removed, etc? Thanks in advance!

Comment: For push notifications to WP8, take a look at Mobile Services. 
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-phone-get-started-push/

Comment: As I mentioned everything is working i.e. topic/queue create, send, receive, delete, send push, receive push. Just I'm missing an event from topic/queue if anything added newly.

Comment: In the c# implementation you can use the Client.OnMessage method witch will poll the subscription for messages. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.onmessageoptions.aspx. I would like to do this in node.js aswell but it seems I have to do the polling manually... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no "notification hook" for when a queue/topic is created. The two options I'd recommend are to either use the service bus management API to periodically scan for new queues/topics, or better yet, set up a "notification topic" which your worker role instances can then listen to. Dropping a message into this topic can be another action performed by the "manager" process when it provisions a new topic/queue.

However, if you could explain the larger scenario of what you're trying to accomplish, I can't help but suspect that there may be a better way to accomplish what you're after. As after a period of time, all those topics/queues could present some management challenges.

Comment: Thanks for reply. For my project I have to use Azure because of push notification, sql database and others. So for my case Azure messaging system is only option i.e topics/queues. Now the scenario. Let's say there is topic named announcement. I big manger send a message by website or mobile client "free beer for all at 13:00 in cafeteria". Everybody should receive a push notification in mobile client "new message in announcement topic".Then Receiver will check topic message after he get notification. Otherwise he has to check topic message every now and then for any new message.

Comment: So you push a notification, then drop a message into a queue that contains additional details related to the notification? Honestly, I don't think topics are your best option here. Instead, I'd stand up a thin façade service tier (mobile services would work fine for this), that can retrieve the message payload from say Azure table storage. This completely removes the need to deal with queue management, consolidate authentication/authorization for the mobile app, and still delivers the same level of functionality at a comparable price point.

Comment: I'm a new Azure developer so I don't know the best option for my goal. The goal is to share one or more messages with several people instantly. This message could be too huge to deliver by push message. Push message is an option to notify user to inform them go and check u got a new message in Azure. In azure it could be   queue, topic, storage or something else. Of course cheaper service is better if I can achieve the same goal. I didn't touch table storage yet.So does table storage has any update event handler and share option? So that I can catch event and send push notification.

Comment: So I'd push back on this. If you were planning on sending a notification in the first place, you have code somewhere that would need to process that event. That code would send the device notification as well as save the extended message payload somewhere for the device user to come back and get. If the trigger for this is another device taking an action (say like sending someone a pic via snapchat or a similar service), the triggering event in all this is the device request. In this case, I would again recommend you take a peak at Mobile services.

Comment: If I were to model this further, I'd say you need to set up a mobile service endpoint that receives a request and saves it to a queue. A web job (new feature), picks up from that queue, saves the payload to blob or table storage, then triggers the device notification for the receivers. Those receivers then make another call to Azure mobile services which in turn retrieves the message payload from where it was stored.

Comment: Web job seems to be just perfect for my requirement. I just read the theory. I have to make a proof of concept to check how it is serving my requirements. Hope there is no impediment regarding web job :). Thanks a lot for all the tips

Answer (score 2):

off course we do have events which notifies the client  when a new message is added to Topic .With message pump mechanism you can hook a client to Topic messages with a valid subscription .

Essentially the code bellow shows how to subscribe to the topic .

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        SubscriptionClient Client = null;

        OnMessageOptions options;
        string connectionString = "your topic Endpoint";

        Client =
           SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString
                   (connectionString, "YourTopicName", "YoursubscriberName");

        // Configure the callback options.
        options = new OnMessageOptions();
        options.AutoComplete = false;
        options.AutoRenewTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

        Client.OnMessage((message) =>
        {
            try
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("Topic Message :  ID :" + message.MessageId + " , " + message.Label);


                message.Complete();



            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {

                message.Abandon();
                Console.WriteLine("**Error Reciving Message**");

            }


        }, options);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long, but it is expected.

Comment: Not sure how a answer gets down voted with out even cross-verifying it :(

Comment: If you got feedbacks as well, listen them, it helps a lot to get more upvotes.